# Poker Probability with hands of 6 cards

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, poker

I am trying to answer Question 1(d). A valid hand would be Ace hearts, 10 hearts, 2 clubs, 7 clubs, Ace spades, J spades.

[image: Question 1]

My attempts have given me 2 different answers that I am unsure of.

What I did was I had to choose 3 suits from 4, then choose 2 cards from each of those suits. When choosing the 2 cards from each suit, do I have to do it 3 times? Would it be **4C3 x (13C2)^3** or **4C3 x 13C2**

Thank you.

Comment: Yes you have to do it three times, once for each of the three suits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are counting ways to select: *two from thirteen* kinds **for each of** *three from four* suits.$$({^{13}\mathrm C_2})^3\cdot{^4\mathrm C_3}$$

---

Note: ${^{13}\mathrm C_2}\cdot{^4\mathrm C_3}$ would count ways to select **the same** *two from thirteen kinds* in *three from four* suits.

Comment: When you say selecting **the same** two from thirteen kinds, do you mean the same 2 numbers for all 3 suits? for example {Ace hearts, 5 hearts, Ace clubs, 5 clubs, Ace spades, 5 spades}

Comment: Yes, indeed.  When allowed to select different kinds, you will have *more* ways to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I have another quick question. I want to know the number of hands with 2 cards from the same suit. I first choose 2 cards from 1 suit giving me 4C1 x 13C2. Then I am unsure how to choose the rest 4 cards. I assume that they are not allowed to be the same suit as the first 2 cards. Would this be **3C1 x 13C4** or **3C1 x (13C1)^4** ?

Comment: @fatimahfatcakes Since there *must* be a suit with *at least* two kinds in the hand, we *should* assume that is asking for a suit with *exactly* two kinds .  Then it becomes as easy as PIE (ie, use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion).$$\def\C#1#2{{^{#1}\mathrm C_{#2}}}\C 41\C{13}2\C{39}4-\C 42(\C{13}{2})^2\,\C{26}2+\C43(\C{13}{2})^3$$

Comment: What is this bit counting? 4C2 x (13C2)^2 x 26C2

Comment: @fatimahfatcakes It is **overcounting** ways to obtain *two from four* suits *each* with *two from their thirteen* kinds, and *two from twenty-six* cards not of those suits.  To *count* the ways you have to subtract ways to obtain *three from four* suits *each* with *two from thirteen* kinds.